# Obtener todos los id al dar click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la siguiente situacion:

Tengo varios checkbox los cuales pueden estar checked o no, y tengo un botón con el cual necesito que seleccione todos los checkbox que no estén seleccionados y aparte de hacer ese cambio necesito saber el id de cada checkbox que se cambio.

Estoy usando JQuery

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input module-permission" id="module_1" name="module_1">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input module-permission" id="module_2" name="module_2">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input module-permission" id="module_3" name="module_3">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger text-white" id="all-modules">TODOS</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando jQuery

```js
$('.btn').click( () => {
  $('.custom-control-input').each( (index, element) => {
    
    console.log( $(element).attr('id') )
    
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input module-permission" id="module_1" name="module_1">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input module-permission" id="module_2" name="module_2">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input module-permission" id="module_3" name="module_3">


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger text-white" id="all-modules">TODOS</button>
```

con `$('.custom-control-input')` capturas todos lo elementos y los puedes iterar por si quieres aplicar una lógica independiente

Comment: Deberías checar tu código, al dar click al botón da `undefined` por consola

Comment: Listo, Ya lo resolví.

Comment: Excelente solucion, me ayudo a resolver el problema, adicional agregue saber si el checbox estaba en checked o no por si a alguien le sirve
if ($(element).is(':checked')) {
   console.log('checked')
} else {         
   console.log('unchecked')               }

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentar esto también, por si no quisieras hacerlo con clases

```js
$('.btn').click( () => {
  //id^="module tomara todos los id que coincidan con module
  $('input[id^="module_"]').each( (index, element) => {
    
    console.log($(element).attr('id'))
    //para imprimir todo el input 
    //console.log(element)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input module-permission" id="module_1" name="module_1">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input module-permission" id="module_2" name="module_2">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input module-permission" id="module_3" name="module_3">


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger text-white" id="all-modules">TODOS</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con JS puro así:

- Capturar todos tus *checkboxes* dentro de una variable, cosa que logras con `querySelectorAll`
- Capturar el botón por medio de su `id` y eso lo almacenas en una variable
- Asignas un listener al botón en su evento `click`
- Cada que el botón sea presionado desencadenará un `forEach` que iterará sobre tu *node list* que recuperaste mas arriba
- Vericicamos si su propiedad `checked` es `true` y en caso de que no lo sea se lo asignamos
- Para verificar el `id` de los checkboxes alcanza con mandar a imprimir la variable y su propiedad `id`

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="checkbox" class="module-permission" id="module_1" name="module_1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="module-permission" id="module_2" name="module_2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="module-permission" id="module_3" name="module_3">
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger text-white" id="all-modules">TODOS</button>
      
    <script>
        let seleccionador = document.getElementById("all-modules")
        let checkBoxes    = document.querySelectorAll(".module-permission")
        seleccionador.addEventListener("click", () => {
            checkBoxes.forEach((element) => {
            if (element.checked) {
              return false
            } else {
              element.checked = true
              console.log(element.id)
            }
            })
        })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```